# establecer marcador en google maps android (API V2)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragment, google-api

tengo estas dos clases que llaman a mi mapa, y mi actividad que lo contiene, el tema es que necesito pasar de la actividad padre, las coordenadas para la actividad hijo, pero no se como hacerlo, si le hago un metodo nuevo que vaya al fragment, para llenar las coordenadas, no se las asigna correctamente, y otra forma no tengo ni idea

> MapViewFragment.java

```
public class MapViewFragment extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.location_fragment);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

> LocalActivity.java

```
    public class LocalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Locales local;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = getContext();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locales);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        int id;
        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
        Servicio ser = new Servicio();
        local = new Locales();
        try {
            local = ser.GetLocal(context, id);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        toolbar.setTitle(local.getNombre());
    }
 }
```

luego tengo mi xml

> content_locales.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    **<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="285dp"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".Fragment.MapViewFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />**

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReservar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/solicitar_reserva" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Actividades totalmente independientes? veo un fragment y una activity

Comment: "el tema es que necesito pasar de la actividad padre, las coordenadas para la actividad hijo", cual es la activity padre y cual hijo.

Comment: pense que lo habia aclarado, error de redaccion, la actividad padre, es la LocalActivity, y la hijo es la MapViewFragment. Saludos @Jorgesys

Comment: @PabloEzequielFerreyra  MapViewFragment es Fragment no Activity, entonces activity_locales.xml contiene el Fragment definido en el layout? En LocalActivity  como cargas el Fragment MapViewFragment ?

Comment: todavia estoy tratando de entender como hice para que me cargue el fragment directamente, porque setee directamente el fragment dentro del activity_locales.xml, y ya me lo abrio, por lo que me llamo poderosamente la atencion, de que no necesitase implementar alguna funcion para llamarlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso debes revisar cual es la `Activity` que agrega o reemplaza en realidad el `Fragment` `MapViewFragment`, para enviar los datos de geo localización desde la Activity que realiza la transacción de `Fragments` lo puedes realizar de esta forma, creando un `bundle` y agregandolo mediante [setArguments()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)) que  proporciona argumentos que se conservarán a través de la destrucción y creación de fragmentos:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Crea bundle.
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putDouble("latitud", 47.1584549);
            bundle.putDouble("longitud", 27.601441799999975);

            //agrega argumentos al Fragment
            MapViewFragment mapFragment = new MapViewFragment();
            mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);

           //Realiza la transacción.
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
            fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout,mapFragment).commit();

  }
```

Para recibir los valores dentro del `Fragment` , se realiza de esta forma:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
 ...
 Bundle bundle = this.getArguments(); //Obtiene los argumentos.

        if(bundle != null) {
            //Obtiene los valores definidos por la key.
            Double latitud = bundle.getDouble("latitud");
            Double longitud = bundle.getDouble("longitud");         
        }
...
}
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: tengo una consulta @Jorgesys, de donde sacas el "fragmentManager"? debido a que cuando lo coloco en el proyecto, no me lo reconoce android studio

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo más completo, declaras FragmentManager fragmentManager;
 y posteriormente para obtener el fragmentManager:  fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); @PabloEzequielFerreyra

Comment: gracias viejo, justo ayer lo vi rebuscando un poco, que faltaba justo esa llamada y salio funcionando

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner directamente las coordenadas en `MapViewFragment.java` y así estableces los marcadores.
Un ejemplo, modifica tu código en `onMapReady` :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    Farmas(googleMap);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);                  
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);  // agrega el botón de localización
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);      // agrega los botones del zoom (+ -)
}

public void Farmas(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    float zoomLevel = 13;      // el nivel del zoom con el cual inicia el mapa

    final  LatLng farma1 = new LatLng(25.6755027,-100.2678697);  // las coordenadas (latitud, longitud) que lo agregas en position
    final  LatLng farma2 = new LatLng(25.672138,-100.2514227);
     // los marcadores (posición, título, ícono):
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(farma1).title("Farmacias Guadalajara 'Centro'").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(farma2).title("Farmacias Guadalajara 'La Pastora'").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(farma1, zoomLevel));  // para mostrar el mapa con zoom, en este caso nivel 13
}
```

Si vas a obtener las coordenadas en otro `fragment`, por ejemplo através de `EditText`, entonces aplica la
solución que da @Jorgesys.